# How to use style and patterns on buttons correctly in Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I need to style a button, but I cant seem to add the lined pattern - its the lines with gaps in it:

For example this works:

```
_btnCloseStyle.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
_btnCloseStyle.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1] CGColor];
```

But this is for a straight line around a button!

```
_btnCloseStyle roundedRectanglePath.lineWidth =0.5;
CGFloat roundedRectanglePattern []
= {5, 5, 5, 5};
[roundedRectanglePath setLineDash: [roundedRectanglePattern count: 4 phase: 0];
[roundedRectanglePath stroke]
```

Ive tried using the above code but its not working.

How is this done correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The Core Graphics code needs to be run in `drawRect` method.

```
[roundedRectanglePath setLineDash: [roundedRectanglePattern count: 4 phase: 0];
[roundedRectanglePath stroke];
```

Create a subclass of the `UIControl` and put this code in `drawRect` method.